# How to convert the Post Order traversal stack implementation to a recursive version

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

This is an assignment related problem but in the requirement they did not ask for how it should be implemented. The input are represented as below:

```
        Input:
        5
        4  1  2
        2  3  4
        5 -1 -1
        1 -1 -1
        3 -1 -1

           4
          / \
         2   5
        / \
       1   3

        Output:
        1 3 2 5 4
```

where 5 is the number of total nodes and each row represents root, left and right node.

Here is my implementation of the PostOrder traversal, which is part of a bigger class:

```
    private int n;
    private int[] _key;
    private int[] _left;
    private int[] _right;

    private List<int> PostOrder()
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>(new int[n]);
        int counter = n-1;
        var stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(0);

        while (stack.Count > 0 && counter > 0)
        {
            int index = stack.Pop();
            result[counter] = _key[index];                

            int leftIndex = _left[index];
            int rightIndex = _right[index];

            if (leftIndex != -1)
                stack.Push(leftIndex);
            if (rightIndex != -1)
                stack.Push(rightIndex);

            counter--;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I was trying to implement the recursive version of this implementation but stuck and can't show my progress. I know how the algorithm works in recursive manner:

```
   PostOrder(root)
   {
      PostOrder(root.left);
      PostOrder(root.right);
      Visit/Print(root);
   }
```

But not sure what would be argument or how should I return when the recursion hits the leaf, given that all the data are represented as arrays? Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. If you wrote the first version and you know the basic structure of the recursive equivalent, what does a desk test suggest you should do? I could just give you the answer, but it seems too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
private void PostOrder(result, index)
{
    if (index == -1)
        return;

    int leftIndex = _left[index];
    int rightIndex = _right[index];

    PostOrder(result, leftIndex);
    PostOrder(result, rightIndex);
    //Add element in Post-Order
    result.add(_key(index));

}


List<int> result = new List<int>();
PostOrder(result, 0);
//result will have the post-order sequence
```